# How to get records from different tables and ignoring duplicated dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's been a long time since I use SQL, so I've been struggling with the following.
I have 2 tables similar to these:

```
Table: Users                       Table: Checker             
             
UID| name | department            UID|        date_time        | entry |  real_entry  
---  -----  ----------            ---  ------------------------  ------  -------------
1  | Anne |  TI                   1  | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  0500 |    0500 
2  | Joe  |  Sales                2  | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  1500 |    1500 
3  | Bob  |  TI                   2  | 2021-02-23 00:00:00.000 |  0600 |    0600 
4  | Ava  |  Sales                3  | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  0500 |    0510 
                                  3  | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  1900 |    1900 
                                  3  | 2021-02-23 00:00:00.000 |  0500 |    0500 
                                  4  | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  1900 |    1910 
                                  4  | 2021-02-19 00:00:00.000 |  0600 |    0610
```

Table checker functions as a digital entry time-clock system for company personnel.
So 'entry' is the hour they supposed to check and 'real_entry' is the hour they actually did.

What I need to obtain is the attendance for the current week per user. If they check two times a day, I just need to retrieve the first one.
The result table should look similar to this:

```
Result:

UID| name | department |        date_time        | entry |  real_entry   
---  -----  ----------   ------------------------  ------  -------------
1  | Anne |  TI        | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  0500 |    0500 
2  | Joe  |  Sales     | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  1500 |    1500 
3  | Bob  |  TI        | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  0500 |    0510 
4  | Ava  |  Sales     | 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 |  1900 |    1910  
2  | Joe  |  Sales     | 2021-02-23 00:00:00.000 |  0600 |    0600 
3  | Bob  |  TI        | 2021-02-23 00:00:00.000 |  0500 |    0500
```

Imagine today is 2021/02/24, which means that the four of them attend on 22, but on 23 just Bob and Joe go.
I didn't count the duplicate entries of the 22 neither the entry of the 19.

For this example the week start should be: '2021-02-22 00:00:00.000'  and the week end should be: '2021-02-28 00:00:00.000'

So far I have this:

```sql
DECLARE @WEEKSTART NVARCHAR(100),
        @WEEKEND   NVARCHAR(100)

SET @WEEKSTART = (SELECT Dateadd(day, 2 - Datepart(weekday, Getdate()), Cast(
                                                  Floor(Cast(Getdate() AS
                                                             FLOAT
                         )) AS DATETIME)))
SET @WEEKEND = (SELECT Dateadd(day, 8 - Datepart(weekday, Getdate()), Cast(
                                              Floor(Cast(Getdate() AS
                                                         FLOAT
                       )) AS DATETIME)))

SELECT checker.uid,
       users.NAME,
       users.department,
       checker.date_time,
       checker.entry,
       checker.entry,
FROM   checker
       INNER JOIN users
               ON users.uid = checker.uid
WHERE  checker.date_time BETWEEN @WEEKSTART AND @WEEKEND
ORDER  BY USER.NAME,
          checker.date_time
```

But with this, I still obtain all the records of the Checker table.

**Any suggestions on how I can achieve the desired result??**

I tried Grouping by Checker.date_time and Checker.UID but I got: is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Which I get, but I can't think of any other solution.

I hope I explained myself well, and thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone is *really* early, you can just use aggregation with `min()`:

```
  SELECT c.UID, u.name, u.department, c.date_time,
         MIN(c.entry), MIN(c.real_entry)   
  FROM Checker c JOIN    
       Users u
       ON u.UID = c.UID    
  WHERE c.date_time BETWEEN @WEEKSTART AND @WEEKEND  
  GROUP BY c.UID, u.name, u.department, c.date_time    
  ORDER BY u.name, c.date_time;
```

If people can be really early (so the second entry is before the first entry), you can use window functions instead:

```
SELECT cu.*
FROM (SELECT u.UID, u.name, u.department,
             c.date_time, c.entry, c.real_entry,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.UID, c.date_time ORDER BY c.entry) as seqnum
      FROM Checker c JOIN    
           Users u
           ON u.UID = c.UID    
      WHERE c.date_time BETWEEN @WEEKSTART AND @WEEKEND
     ) cu
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using an extra Temp table with Row Number to find the first entry.

```
        DECLARE @WEEKSTART NVARCHAR(100),
                @WEEKEND NVARCHAR(100)
    
        SET @WEEKSTART = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), cast( floor( cast( getdate() as float)) as datetime)))
        SET @WEEKEND = (SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 8 -  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) , cast( floor( cast( getdate() as float)) as datetime)))

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempResult
         SELECT CH.UID,
               U.name,
               U.department,
               CH.date_time,
               CH.entry,
               CH.Real_Entry,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY U.name,CH.date_time order by CH.entry) AS EntryOrder
               INTO #TempResult
          FROM Checker CH         
          JOIN Users U ON U.UID = CH.UID          
          WHERE CH.date_time BETWEEN @WEEKSTART AND @WEEKEND    
          ORDER BY U.name, CH.date_time
    
         SELECT UID,
                name,
                department,
                date_time,
                entry,
                Real_Entry 
        FROM #TempResult 
        WHERE EntryOrder = 1
```